# Maven Install Failed with POM Error in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, maven

I get the following error when I "Maven Install" in Sprint Tool Suite 4.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen <!DOCTYPE html>\n<html ng-app="artifactory.ui">... @2:31)  @ C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom, line 2, column 31
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project OGITS:hogehoge.API:1.0.0 (C:\Workspaces\hogehogeRepo\hogehogeAPIServer\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom: Expected root element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen <!DOCTYPE html>\n<html ng-app="artifactory.ui">... @2:31)  @ C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom, line 2, column 31 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please show the pom.xml file

Comment: Looks like a corrupted POM in your Maven cache. I would try deleting the folder `C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent` and then rerunning maven install.  This should force Maven to re-download this package.  If it fails again, try opening the POM file mentioned in the error message: it looks like an HTML error page was received instead of an XML file, and maybe this file will contain a clue as to what has gone wrong.

Comment: I strongly recommend to check the checksum policy see https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/